# Is "cyclic endomorphism" a proper English mathematical wording?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Consider a vector space $V$ of finite dimension equal to $n$ and an endomorphism $u$ of $V$. In French, an endomorphism $u$ for which it exists a vector $v$ such that $\{v, u(v), \dots, u^{n-1}(u)\}$ spans $V$ is called an **endomorphisme cyclique**.

It seems that in English $v$ is called a **cyclic vector for $u$**, but I'm not sure that the wording $u$ is a **cyclic endomorphism** exists.

What's your view on the question?

Comment: Does this question fit math stackexchange at all? We don't deal with language problems here. Perhaps it should be posted on https://english.stackexchange.com/ ? Anyway voting to close.

Comment: I am dismayed to see that this question was put on hold. Well, anything and everything, you choose. It is obviously not a question of language; here we are talking about a notation.In fact the notation "cyclic matrix" is used page 322 in the book of D. Bernstein: "Matrix Mathematics, Theory, Facts and Formulas. I voted to reopen...

Comment: Googling "cyclic endomorphism" finds some hits but not as many as I expected. Anyway, the problem with the question is that is opinion-based. I'd rather the question remains open, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won’t use cyclic endomorphism in writing without defining it as it seems not commonly used.